# "a:InternalServiceFault" getting error when calling SOAP service

Tags: qt, soap, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

friends..

I am implementing SOAP webservices..

I am using below code..

```
QtSoapMessage request;
request.setMethod(QtSoapQName("Method_Name", "http://tempuri.org/*****/"));

request.addMethodArgument("key1", "", "value1");
request.addMethodArgument("key2", "", "value2");

QString action ="http://tempuri.org/****/MethodName";

QString host ="host name";
QString prefix ="/****/****.svc";
```

I am getting response like below..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be needing the URI in your addMethodArgument.
Besides, how do you run the request? Is this all the code?